# Starting a new thread causes an Android app to terminate

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am currently working on a simple android app, which on a pressed button must start a networking thread. The networking thread listens for something new on the socket and reads it. The problem is that, when I press the button the application crashes. I was able to track down the error and it says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

So, in the `onCreate()` I initialize the button and I say the following:

```
 fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new ClientSide().run();
        }
    });
```

The ClientSide is a separately written .java file consisting of two threads:

1. The first one initializes some parameters, connects to the socket
2. The second one listens and writes from/to the socket (`class TextDataTransmitter extends Thread`)

   ```
   public class ClientSide extends RuntimeException implements Runnable{
   ...
   System.out.println("Thread activated!");
   // Connect to the chat server...}
   ```

   The compilation doesn't even reach the `System.out.println("Thread blablabla")`...

Please guys advice me what to do in order to make this crash disappear. I am still far from being advanced at android development. If you need more info or code, I'll be ready to provide it.

Comment: ALso, calling Run does not start a thread.  Thread.start() starts a thread.  Calling run on a Runnable runs it in the current thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan good but just two more things. Isn't the AsyncTask for threads which last for just a couple of seconds? In my case the thread I use should be constantly running alongside the UI (main) one, I guess. Correct me if I'm wrong, if I say ClientSide.run() it will mean that I will be running it within the main thread, not on background as a separate process? And vice versa - ClientSide.start()  will run it on background?

Comment: AsyncTask is a good thread replacement if you need it for a couple of seconds and then update the UI, like downloading an image.  If you need it to run for a long time then you want a normal Thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you, ok and how about the second question? (sorry for asking so much, it is fundamental, I need to get it :D :D :D  )

Comment: No you have to make a new Thread object and pass it ClientSide as a runnable in its constructor.  Then call start on the Thread.  It will launch a new OS level thread, then call run on that new thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you so much, excuse me for taking you so much time, if there was a like-this-post kind of option in the comment section I'd had voted for those answers, thanks.